# Getting Method name and Parameters form AOP Invocation class

Tags: java, jboss, ejb-3.0, aop

I have created a custom AOP interceptor and configured it in jboss 6 -> deploy-> ejb3-interceptor-aop.xml file under the domain "Stateless Bean". Now all requests to any Stateless Bean are intercepted by the custom interceptor:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.jboss.aop.advice.Interceptor;
import org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.Invocation;

public class SimpleInterceptor implements Interceptor {

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "SimpleInterceptor";
}

@Override
public Object invoke(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {

    System.out.println("SimpleInterceptor - Logging BEFORE calling method :"+invocation);
    Object localObject1 = invocation.invokeNext();
    System.out.println("SimpleInterceptor - Logging AFTER calling method :");
    return localObject1;
}

}
```

But how can I identify which Stateless Bean have been invoked through the custom interceptor, because `org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.Invocation` class doesn't provide method details nor input parameters. So is there any option to extract the method name and input parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting arguments:
https://docs.jboss.org/jbossaop/docs/2.0.0.GA/docs/aspect-framework/apidocs/org/jboss/aop/joinpoint/MethodInvocation.html#getArguments()

For getting method details:
https://docs.jboss.org/jbossaop/docs/2.0.0.GA/docs/aspect-framework/apidocs/org/jboss/aop/joinpoint/MethodInvocation.html#getMethod%28%29

Comment: thanks @Deepak, Its working.
`MethodInvocation mInv = (MethodInvocation) invocation;`
`System.out.println("SimpleInterceptor - Logging BEFORE calling method :" + mInv.getMethod());`